# How to fix the alignment of my portfolio website?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and trying to build my first portfolio website.

I'm having a few difficulties and was wondering if someone could lead me in the right direction. I want my navigation bar to stay fixed so that as you scroll down the page, it doesn't move. BUT all body items aren't aligning properly. I can't seem to get my image, the table, and the objective to align properly.

What I would like to happen:

- The image is to the far left of the page, centered, and below the navigation bar
- The table aligns right below the image (wherever image is, so is the table)
  p.s. the table is just links to my social media accounts
- The objective is to the right of the page, next to the image but lots of space between them
- The title is above the objective (wherever objective is, so is the title)
- In conclusion: to the right of the page should be objective and title, and to the left of the page should be image and table

Problems I'm having:

- Title is hidden behind navigation bar
- Table, image, and objective won't align properly

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

---

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>FULL NAME</title>
</head> 

<body> 

<div id="center">
<h1>NAME</h1>
<img src="#"/a>
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#"><img src="#"/></a></td>
<td><a href="#"><img src="#"/></a></td>
<td><a href="#"><img src="#"/></a></td>
<td><a href="#"><img src="#"/></a></td>
<td><a href="#"><img src="#"/></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<h4>Objective<h4>

</div>

<div id="navigation"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="#">MENU ITEM</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU ITEM</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU ITEM</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU ITEM</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU ITEM</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="footer">
<div id="bottom">
<p> &copy; All Rights Reserved by FULL NAME<span class="em"></span></p></div>
</div>
</body>     
</html>
```

---

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 960px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Sans-serif;
}

#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
}

#navigation  li {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: -20px;
    padding-right: -20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Georgia, Serif, Times;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#navigation ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    color: #00131C;
}

#navigation a:link, a:visited {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    background-color:#000000; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding:6px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    display: block;
} 

#navigation a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    color: #000000;
}

#circle{
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: center;
}

.center {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    top: 100px;
    float: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.center img {
    float: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.center p {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    top: -100px;
}

.center p{
  width: 50%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: top;
}

.center table {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    position: center;
}

table img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: center;
    position: center:
}

#footer{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3 px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0;
}

#bottom p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: -20px;
    padding-right: -20px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Georgia, Serif, Times;
    float: center;
    position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are are somethings that are wrong with your code:

- Your are using `<div id="center">` in your html, however your CSS is referencing the class `center`
- `float: center;` and `position: center;` is invalid css to center objects. For more info on how to center objects see http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

I think that you want to something like this http://jsfiddle.net/vAuFA/